# Как убрать значение integer в нативном классе PHP?

Tags: php, snmp

Есть код по сбору данных по SNMP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once('../function.php');
$db = new Database;
$row = $db->select('offices', 'ip_office','', 'status_office = 1');
foreach($row as $value){
  $snmp = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $value['ip_office'], 'public');
  $result[] = $snmp->get(array(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0", "iso.3.6.1.4.1.14988.1.1.17.1.1.4.1", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.1"));
  $snmp->close();
}
include_once('index.php');
```

Результатом вывода, к примеру, является:

```
STRING: "g. New York, ul. Baker, d. 6"
STRING: "RouterOS v6.43.15 Nov/14/2018 15:04:25"
INTEGER: 1
```

Как убрать обозначения строк integer или string?

Comment: обработайте результирующую строку, в чем сложность то?

Comment: @teran, я имею ввиду нативно как убрать. К примеру, можно использовать библиотеку snmp_get и там командной snmp_set_quick_print(1) можно убрать подобный вывод, а оставить только значения. Хочется использовать встроенный класс.

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось банально просто. Решается с помощью вызова метода [`snmp_set_quick_print()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.snmp-set-quick-print.php)

```
include_once('../function.php');
$db = new Database;
$row = $db->select('offices', 'ip_office','', 'status_office = 1');

snmp_set_quick_print(1);

foreach($row as $value){
  $snmp = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $value['ip_office'], 'public');
  $result[] = $snmp->get(array(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0", "iso.3.6.1.4.1.14988.1.1.17.1.1.4.1", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.1"));
  $snmp->close();
}
include_once('index.php');
```